# Passing array of type char** as an argument of type void** gives unexpectable warning

Tags: c, eclipse, sublimetext3

I have a warning when passing a pointer array (char**) as an argument of type void** in a function.

Below is my code. I use gcc compiler, it gives me this warning:

> "warning: passing argument 1 of 'print' from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]".

It points to this line `print(lineptr, 2);`

And another warning says:

> warning: format '%s' expects argument of type 'char *', but argument 2 has type 'void *'.

And it points to this line `printf("%s\n", *v++);`

I tried replacing all `void**` with `char**` and it works well.

The reason that I want to use `void**` is that I'm writing a quicksort function that can receive both character or integer arrays.

```
#include <stdio.h>
char *lineptr[100] = {"mister", "x"};
void print(void **, int n);
int main()
{
    print(lineptr, 2);
    return 0;
}
void print(void **v, int n)
{
    while( n-- > 0 )
        printf("%s\n", *v++);
}
```

**The question is: does this warnings affect anything?**

Now, I'm having no problems running the code and getting a desired output, but I asks if this method is guaranteed to work well every time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could cast the `char` array to `void`:

```
print((void **)lineptr, 2);
```

Generally it's best to pay attention to warnings and fix the issues to avoid undefined behavior.

Comment: This works for Array of pointers. [How would you handle it with](https://pastebin.com/raw/fnPGW6R0) `char[][]` ? Where cast increases required alignment of target type.

Comment: Thank you. Your solutions removed the two warnings.

Comment: But now why a book like k&r don't use these casts in it's examples? (I talk here about the qsort example in section 5.11)

Answer (score 0):

While you can use the %s for your current lineptr, you say that you might use the same function for int arrays. This will crash. Also, your current implementation doesn't specify the size of the int arrays. I might be missing something.

How would you define your int array? Would you be sorting the contents of the int array or sorting arrays of integers, the same as you are currently sorting arrays of characters?